# Leasing Question

Tags: car, auto-leasing

I leased a vehicle for 39 months. At the time they told me I was allowed 12,000 miles a year. On the contract I and the dealer signed where it says not to exceed a certian amount of miles or .25 per mile over they left it blank. Is that to my advantage???

Comment: So nowhere in your contract does it actually say how many miles you are allowed?

Comment: A tag to indicate where you are will help, but in many places, an oral contract is still binding (although obviously harder to prove).

Comment: You’ve sifted through every word of that contract, and don’t find the 39,000 mile total allowance anywhere?

Comment: Instead of thinking of this as a possible advantage, I'd be equally interested to confirm that they didn't write the lease based on less than 39K miles.

Answer (score 1):

You should still proceed carefully. I understand the paper you signed didn't have the mileage limitation on, but:

- There's a strong chance they're storing it electronically, which
  could catch you out.
- The form you're looking at might be your copy, so the mileage
  limitation didn't need to be written on there.
- There's also a small chance that this was left blank and then filled
  in after you drove off the forecourt.

That last point would be pretty crappy of the dealership, but it seems odd that the dealer signed the form with the mileage limit blank (maybe an honest mistake), but it's easy / extra revenue for them.

When you're coming towards the end of the lease, the dealership will contact you, and you'll be reminded your mileage limitation and fees.

Alternatively, if you have a few more years left and want to make the most of the mileage, then you can call them up and ask to be reminded.